# unexpected token: BillingState

Tags: apex, soql, batch, dynamic-soql

Im learning more about Batch Apex class and I find it pretty cool and helpful.  When I remove the Where BillingSate='TX' everything works as expected.  Yet when I use the Where condition I get the following error: **First error: unexpected token: BillingState** What does this error mean?

Things I considered: I have made sure the query works by using the Query Editor. The Contacts don't have any values in their MailingState fields.  I have access to all fields as a system admin. I get the same error even after using variable binding.

```
/*String state = 'TX';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'Select id,BillingStreet,BillingCity,BillingState,'+
        'BillingPostalCode,(Select id,MailingStreet,MailingCity,'+
        'MailingState,MailingPostalCode from Contacts) From Account'+
        'where BillingState=:'+state
        );  This doesn't work either */
global class UpdateContactAddInfo implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'Select id,BillingStreet,BillingCity,BillingState,'+
        'BillingPostalCode,(Select id,MailingStreet,MailingCity,'+
        'MailingState,MailingPostalCode from Contacts) From Account'+
        'where BillingState=\'TX\''
        );
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope)
    {
        List<Contact> contacts=new List<Contact>();
        for(Account a:scope)
        {
            for(Contact c:a.contacts)
            {
                c.MailingStreet = a.BillingStreet;
                c.MailingCity = a.BillingCity;
                c.MailingState = a.BillingState;
                c.MailingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode;
                contacts.add(c);
                  
            }
        }
      update contacts;
    } 
    global void finish(database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space after `FROM Account`, which is a constant pitfall when building queries through string concatenation.

This would be easier to see if you did not use Dynamic SOQL here, since you do not need it. Just write a static SOQL query:

```apex
return Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT Id, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState,
           BillingPostalCode,
           (SELECT Id, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode 
            FROM Contacts)
    FROM Account
    WHERE BillingState='TX'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you! that solved it.  I will definitely remember this.